# Adding html / css within JavaScript toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
$('#toggle3').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').hide('1000');
    $('.toggle').text('I would like to add a navigation menu here'); // <--
$('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

return false; 
    });
});
```

I am wondering the best way to edit the above code snippet to be able to hold HTML / CSS as I plan on calling a custom menu within. I will be using this snippet multiple times and calling multiple menus to trigger with toggle.

Comment: Well you would use html, not text

Comment: Thanks! But hey; using simple html does work; but does that make most sense with adding a content menu? Like that amount of code?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, try to avoid embedding html on javascript: you're likely to run into escaping issues and multiline strings, and the overall result usually isn't pretty.

You might want to store the HTML on the DOM itself:

```
<div>
  <span class="toggle" data-toggle="foo">Toggle foo</span>
  <span class="toggle" data-toggle="bar">Toggle bar</span>
</div>

<div id="navmenu-store">
  <div class='navmenu' data-for-toggle="foo">
    navmenu "foo"
  </div>

  <div class='navmenu' data-for-toggle="bar">
    navmenu "bar"
  </div>
</div>
```

On the CSS, hide the 'store':

```css
#navmenu-store {
  display: none;
}
```

And then, with javascript, add the navmenus when requested:

```
$(".toggle").each(function() {
  var $toggle = $(this);
  var toggleName = $toggle.data("toggle");  
  var $navmenu = $(".navmenu[data-for-toggle=" + toggleName + "]");

  // Store the navmenu on the toggle for later access
  $navmenu.remove();
  $toggle.data("navmenu", $navmenu);
});

$(".toggle").on("click", function() {
  var $toggle = $(this);
  var $navmenu = $toggle.data("navmenu");

  var isInTheDom = $.contains(document, $navmenu[0]);

  if(isInTheDom) {
    $navmenu.remove();
  } else {
    // Here I'm inserting the navmenu after the toggle;
    // you can do whatever you want
    $navmenu.insertAfter($toggle);
  }
});
```

I've created a very simple jsbin as a proof of concept: http://jsbin.com/OwUWAlu/1/edit